# Unable to get color of a cell when calling function in a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the display color of a cell in Excel. Thus, I use the following function:

```
Function get_color()
  get_color = Cells(1,1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Function
```

When calling this function from a procedure, it works well. However, I'm unable to assign its return value to a cell. Indeed, writing in B12

```
=get_color()
```

yields a VALUE error.

Conventionally, the member Color of the class Interior is a *Variant* object which is in fact a Long, so the problem is not that Excel can't assign an exotic value to a cell.

How am I suppose to get the apparent color of a cell and write it into another cell?

Comment: If this cell is formatted by conditional formatting the short answer is you can't from a udf called from the worksheet. Displayformat does not works called from the worksheet. And only displayformat can see conditional formatting. It would be better to test the rule that causes the formatting than test the formatting.

Comment: @ScottCraner Indeed, I'm using conditional formatting. Is it possible to check a conditional formatting rule without having to write it twice ? The goal is to avoid users having to use VBA when modifying the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work just removing the `.DisplayFormat` part, so that it becomes `get_color = Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color`.
You can also try the following in order to be able to catch the color of a given cell:

```
Function get_color(myCell As Range) As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  get_color = ws.Cells(myCell.Row, myCell.Column).Interior.Color
End Function
```

You can use it in your code like this: `a = get_color(Range("A1"))` or in the worksheet like this: `=get_color(A1)`

Comment: If the cell is colored through conditional formatting, this will fail to return the color.